# Can you target IE10 Metro with conditional tags?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have a page and the width of a field displays find across all browsers and OS combos but in `IE10 Metro` the content drops down to the next line because the field isn't wide enough apparently.

I don't want to extend the width of the field any more as I have already had to do that for `Firefox` on `OSx` and other IE variants; so didn't want to make it any wider across the board.

Is there a way I can target `IE10 Metro` with conditional tags or other - like other IE's?

Comment: Have you tried targeting it and it's not working?

Comment: Microsoft drop support for conditional comments in IE 10: http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/

Comment: @BillyMoat Well I have tried targeting `IE10` before itself and it didn't work, and just found out via another SO post that IE10 no longer reads conditional comments; so I guess targeting Metro is out too!?

Comment: @kmb385 Yeah, just found that out via another SO post. :( Perhaps will have to resort to JS or just extend the field even longer.

Comment: @Brett I wonder if jquery built anything in yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to detect `IE10 Metro` since IE 10 has dropped conditional comments.  Source: http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/

One solution maybe to use Javascript feature detection in order to determine the browser.